# jq function with boolean parameter does not reverse input array

Tags: jq

I would like to reverse an array with a jq function.

The jq function accepts a boolean that tells the function whether or not to reverse the array.

Strangely enough, this function is returning `true` instead of returning the (possibly sorted) array...

### jq Filter

```
def reverseIfTrue($reverse):
  if $reverse then reverse else . end;
reverseIfTrue(true)
```

### json Input

```
["a","b"]
```

### jq Output

```
true
```

jq snippet: https://jqplay.org/s/DMMUme_Qngi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that the name of the parameter is colliding with the name of the filter, essentially creating a local that obscures the global. Naming the parameter anything else will fix it:

```
def reverseIfTrue($rev):
  if $rev then
    reverse
  else
    .
  end
;
```

Remember that filter parameters always create their non-variable aliases; `def foo($bar): ...` is documented to be the same as `def foo(bar): bar as $bar | ...`.

Comment: interesting, I did not know that $reverse would collide with reverse since $reverse has a $ ...

Comment: @tg0h Variables don't generally collide with functions of the same name. The collision here happens only with function arguments because `def name($f): …;` is just a [shortcut for](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#DefiningFunctions) `def name(f): f as $f | …;`, which reveals the collision. Also, the collision only happens within the function body; elements outside of this function are not affected, even if they are executed due to a call from within this function. So, you only ran into this because you were naming an argument as a function you were actually using in the same context.